# Is there free book-writing software without the page break?

Tags: gratis, macos, books

Is there a software for book writing like LibreOffice or Pages where you can write without having trouble with the page break? (In LibreOffice you can scale it, but that's not really what I'm looking for.)

(MacOS, stuck in the update before Catalina due to storage problems)

**System:**

- MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
- v10.14.3 Mojave

Comment: What functionality do you need in book writing? Would a simple Markdown editor like https://typora.io/ be enough? Afaik in LibreOffice and Microsoft Word you can double-click the space between pages to collapse those margins; would that be good enough for you?

Comment: Typora looks nice. Thank you! Will I be able to release my writings to the public using it (default file formats)?

Comment: Yes, you can use Pandoc to export Markdown to a PDF, docx, or EPUB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Markdown editor such as [Typora](https://typora.io/). Typora supports exporting to PDF, and for other formats such as docx or EPUB, you can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). See https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/ if you need a primer on Markdown syntax.

Typora is currently in beta and is free during beta, but will presumably not be free after a stable release comes out. Another option might be [MacDown](https://macdown.uranusjr.com/), which has a split view between the Markdown syntax and the rendered display version.

Comment: Typora now stopped being free.